# Global application data in Meteor

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I'm trying to set global application data  in `lib/config.js` (maybe it should be in something more like `settings.js` or `settings.json`) like so:

```
AppData = {
  name : 'Foo',
  author : 'Mr. Bar',
  socialLinks : [
    { name : 'FaceSpace' , url : 'facespace.com/foo' },
    { name : 'Twitgram'  , url : 'twitgram.net/foo'  }
  ]
}
```

So I can use it in various templates like `head.html`:

```
<title>{{AppData.name}}</title>
```

Or `home.html`:

```
<h1>Welcome to {{AppData.name}}</h1>
```

Or `footer.html`:

```
{{#each AppData.socialLinks}}
  <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
{{/each}}

...

<p>Created by {{AppData.author}}</p>
```

I tried searching for examples of this pattern with no luck. It's quite possible I'm asking the wrong questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a [template helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper) (set somewhere in your `client` folder) to communicate your data to your views, like so:

```
Template.registerHelper('AppData', function () {
    return AppData;
  });
```

This way your views, as well as your javascript code, will be able to access your `AppData` object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This doesn't seem to be working for me. In the same file I can `console.log()` the `AppData` out successfully but I don't have access to it once my application loads. Thoughts?

Comment: Hm... where did you put the code I wrote and your view files? What outputs when you simply try {{AppData}} ?

Comment: For simplicity's sake, I have your code in `cleint/settings.js` with `AppData` defined in the same file just above the helper. All of my views are in the root `client` folder as well. I spun up another project to test this.

Comment: `{{AppData}}` returns nothing.  FWIW, I noticed if I change `Template.registerHelper` to `Template.myTemplate.helpers` everything works as expected for `myTemplate`.

Comment: Ah, 'tis a shame.... [Wrong syntax on my part](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper). Answer edited.

Comment: Huzzah! Thank you, that was it! I feel like I've been stuck on trying to implement incorrect syntax for weeks.